# Cannot Teleport a Player to coordinates set in a config file [Bukkit]

Tags: java, bukkit

So I am basicly making a Warping system but I am using it for a minigame. I want the owners of the server to be able to set the warp for the different players to spawn in when the minigame starts. For some reason, I am getting a error which is saying that I cannot teleport the player, here is my code for the teleporting part:

```
    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("cakestart")){

            if(getConfig().contains("locations." + args[0])){
                int locationsX = this.getConfig().getInt("locations" + args[0] + ".X");
                int locationsY = this.getConfig().getInt("locations" + args[0] + ".Y");
                int locationsZ = this.getConfig().getInt("locations" + args[0] + ".Z");
                int locationsYaw = this.getConfig().getInt("locations" + args[0] + ".Yaw");
                int locationsPitch = this.getConfig().getInt("locations" + args[0] + ".Pitch");
                Object locationsworld = this.getConfig().get("locations" + args[0] + ".World");

                Location cakestart = new Location((World) locationsworld, locationsX, locationsY, locationsZ, locationsYaw, locationsPitch);

                p.teleport(cakestart);
                p.sendMessage("TPED!");
            }

        }
```

The error is happening with:

```
        p.teleport(cakestart);
```

I can give any more info you need.

Comment: What is the StackTrace? (What shows up in console)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that instead of

```
Object locationsworld = this.getConfig().get("locations" + args[0] + ".World");
Location cakestart = new Location((World) locationsworld, locationsX, locationsY, locationsZ, locationsYaw, locationsPitch);
```

You instead define locationsworld as a string, and then fetch the actual world from the server using it's unique case-sensitive name. Assuming you're in your main class that extends JavaPlugin, it would look like this:

```
String locationsworld = this.getConfig().get("locations" + args[0] + ".World");
World tworld = this.getServer().getWorld(locationsworld);
Location cakestart = new Location(tworld, locationsX, locationsY, locationsZ, locationsYaw, locationsPitch);
```

That way you don't have an invalid world. There's a lot more info in the world class that just a name, and unless you're saving all of it instead of just the `World.getName();`, you're not going to have much success with a typecast.

**EDIT:** Afterthought: You would also probably do well to use doubles instead of integers for the other values, especially pitch and yaw.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the Object cannot be cast to the World object. I would try saving the world as a string and parsing it to a world object using `Bukkit.getWorld("string");`.

To get a World from the config all you have to do is this:

```
Bukkit.getWorld(getConfig().getString("path of the world in the config");
```

Comment: You're missing a `)` there.